# Find the intersecting area of more than 2 polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, intersection, area

I have a map of 7 species distributions. I want to create polygons of the area where all 7 overlap, 6 overlap, 5 overlap etc. I created a polygon of where any 2 species overlap using the intersect tool under geoprocessing tools. However it would be incredibly tedious to do this for the area where more than 2 polygons intersect because I would have to merge all possible combination of shp. files. Is there a way to do this besides that?

Comment: This may be easier to do with rasters, you could add them all together and then exclude all areas that do not add to 7.